# My new Laravel project doesn't start correctly

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using windows 10 and I'm totally new in Laravel and PHP

I installed php, composer, node, npm and Laravel and wrote my first command in powershell

```
laravel new myNewSite
```

Then I got this error, I don't know what is it:

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
> Problem 1
> - laravel/framework[v8.65.0, ..., 8.x-dev] require league/flysystem ^1.1 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[1.1.0, ..., 1.x-dev].
> - league/flysystem[1.1.0, ..., 1.x-dev] require ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's fileinfo extension.
> - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^8.65 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v8.65.0, ..., 8.x-dev].
> To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
> - C:\Program Files\php-8.0.13\php.ini
> You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

I looked for a solution and I came up with deleting the beginning ; in extension=fileinfo in php.ini-development and php.ini-production files but nothing changed, the same error still exists. So what should I do?

Comment: the configuration is only ever read from `php.ini` the other 2 files you mentioned are meant to be example files for development and production respectively. If you don't have a `php.ini` then copy the `php-development.ini` as `php.ini`

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem

I copied my file path

```
 C:\Program Files\php-8.0.13\php.ini
```

I pasted it in the explorer bar

PHP file Notepad came up in the screen

I looked for ;extension=fileinfo and found it

I deleted the beginning ;

I saved the file

that's it guys!